# How can you create a board in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, kanban, azure-boards

*I ran into this problem and solved it, so this Q&A is here just in case somebody else spent time on sifting through Microsoft's docs trying to find this answer*.

How do you create a new board in Azure DevOps? When I go to the boards > board and look at my existing boards, there's no + button to create like there is with repositories in the board list dropdown. Additionally, there's not an add button in the top right. And the board settings are just board preferences, not overall boards management.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As it turns out, in Azure DevOps you can only create boards by creating a team. The team board is created as a side-effect of creating the team. Merely creating a board without the team isn't possible in their paradigm as of this writing.

Sources:

[Manage and configure team tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/manage-teams)
[Configure and customize Azure boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/configure-customize?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)

Comment: So you can't create a per-sprint board? This is unfortunate!

Comment: You can filter the team's board by sprint. To put items on a sprint, you can drag them on the [Product Backlog Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/assign-work-sprint?view=azure-devops). I expected this to be on a board rather than the backlog (like GitLab), so I didn't find it before finding this help.  Not quite as flexible as GitLab, but also not as bad as I thought it was at first.

Comment: The comment from user 'JamesQMurphy' on 2023-09-26 is missing context regarding the date of the changed behavior -- previously, the 'sprint taskboard' didn't exist. That person's original comment reads: "yes you can. There are two types of boards... the Kanban Board (of which there is one per team) and the Sprint Taskboard, which is the per-sprint board you are thinking of"