# How to effectively manage Task and Bug work items on the same Sprints page Taskboard if the WIT have different states?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

The problem that I have is that the existing ADO Project has only used Azure Boards for Test Plans and Bug WIT. They haven't used Boards for tracking Epics, Features, User Stories, and Tasks up to this point, but they want to start now **within only 1 (TeamA) of the 4 teams**.

The Bug type has been customized with many states that clearly won't align with a Task.
[image]

When I remove columns from the TeamA's taskboard that match the Bug WIT's states, ADO gives me an error.
[image]

I am thinking that due to the above limitation and [this limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61502817/how-can-you-create-a-board-in-azure-devops), I will need to not use this configuration
[image]
and I will not be able to display Bugs on TeamA's Sprint Taskboard.

I am open to proposed solutions.